# Узнать Id к записи во время добавления

Tags: sql, база-данных

Пишу страницу добавления материала и нужно сохранить картинку с именем id материала т.е. `id.jpg`.

Но как узнать Id будущей строки в БД. Есть идея добавить любое значение и обновить по макс id, а это получается 2 запроса к БД. И мне интересно можно ли по-проще узнать Id

Comment: сделай insert записи о новой фотке и уже получившийся id юзай для переименования файла

Comment: 1) Большинство диалектов имеют средства получения последнего сгенерированного значения. Специфично для каждой СУБД. 2) Кто мешает после вставки сделать SELECT с только что вставлеными значениями во WHERE и получить вожделенный ID.

Answer (score 0):

Если у таблицы используется автоинкремент, то сделайте запрос «SHOW TABLE STATUS ...». Он возвращает ряд полей, в том числе **Auto_increment**, который указывает на следующее значение автоинкремента.

Линк: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/SHOW_TABLE_STATUS.html